# Filling Datagridview with data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to fill up my datagridview based on query. Basically that query is being applied to a view I created in my sql server which is a join of 3 table. Here is my code:

```
Database a = new Database();
string ConStr = @"Data Source=HO-IT-WS-06;Initial Catalog=VMS;Integrated Security=True";
con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
con.Open();
String theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
String query = "SELECT cnic, name, comp_name, date_in, date_out, time_in," + 
        "time_out, chk_in, chk_out from visitor_status where date_in= @theDate";
SqlCommand sqlCmdStatement = new SqlCommand(query, con);
sqlCmdStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", theDate);
//dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con); //c.con is the connection string
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; 
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Exception:

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@theDate".
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at Visitor_Management_System.People_Checked_In_On_Specific_Date.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Jaali Copy\Visitor Management System\Visitor Management System\People Checked In On Specific Date.cs:line 61
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
ClientConnectionId:1afac376-fc05-4a77-ab81-8278cb908602
```

However it gives exception on the Line **dataAdapter.Fill(ds);** saying that must declare the scalar value @date. What's wrong here? Why is my datagridview not being filled? Can queries be applied to views in c#?

Comment: what is the datatype of `date_in`. is it string or datetime?

Comment: data type of date_in is date in my table.

Comment: you have mentioned that you are using joined query of 3 tables but in your code sample i can't see any joins ??

Comment: i have done that in sql server. There has been made a new view that is combination of 3 tables . It exists on server am just accessing it. here. That view is visitor_status!

Comment: Why datagridview tag is required in this question @KarthikAMR

Comment: @Nimesh Please understand the question

Comment: Can you describe it how datagridview related to the problem? @KarthikAMR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert string value in @theDate parameter.

Try This,

```
DateTime theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
String query = "SELECT cnic, name, comp_name, date_in, date_out, time_in, time_out," +
     "chk_in, chk_out from visitor_status where date_in= @theDate";
SqlCommand sqlCmdStatement = new SqlCommand(query, con);
sqlCmdStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", theDate);
```

Change SqlDataAdapter declaration as

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmdStatement);
```

---

if the in_date field or dateTimePicker1 containing time then you have to remove it like this.

```
//Remove time from DateTimePicker
DateTime theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

//Remove time from field
Where Convert(smalldatetime,Convert(char(10),date_in,103),103) = @theDate
```

Comment: same exception at the same line

Comment: @user3441306 please show me the full error message.

Comment: The problem is here `SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);` you are creating a parameter in SqlCommandObject and you are creating SqlDataAdapter object using SQL Query.

Comment: Replace that line with `SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmdStatement);`

Comment: no exception now but nothing is being displayed in the datagrid!

Comment: is `in_date` field containing `time` like '2014-03-21 15:45'?